# To transfer tokens from owner address to an address, if latter address moves some other tokens to a given particular address

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, erc-20

I am writing a contract for an ERC20 token (say ABC). Is it possible to airdrop some of these newly minted ABC tokens to those ERC20 addresses, every time, if they transfer a different token (named BCD) to a particular ERC20 address?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. There are two ways to do it:

1) In the `transfer` function of `BCD` token, you would check if the transfer is send to the particular erc20 address in question. If the transfer is being made to the desired address, you would call the `mint` function on `ABC` token and mint these tokens in the same transaction. The code would look something like:

```
function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns (bool success) {
    ...
    if (to == desiredAddress) {
        ABC(abcAddress).mint(to, value);
    }
    ...
}
```

2) (If you cannot edit the `transfer` function of `BCD`) You can set up an offchain watcher that would view each `BCD` token transaction. This watcher would watch for each `BCD` token transfer and perform the `ABC` mint if it is required. This would cost you, the watcher, each time new `ABC` is minted.

**Note**

Option #1 is *technically* abiding by the ERC20 standard, but it would be hard for other services to integrate the `BCD` token because of the fact that it may do something unexpected for their service.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok, but it will be a little more complex, you need to check many things to confirm it safe enough. But anyway it's a good chance to polish up web3 skill. Let's go.

This task can be done by listening for an event that is emitted when a transfer of the BCD token occurs and then checking if the recipient of the transfer is the specified ERC20 address. If it is, you can use the transfer function to airdrop the ABC tokens to the recipient's address. Here is some example code to demonstrate:

```
// Import the required libraries
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

// Import the BCD token contract
import "BCDToken.sol";

// Import the ABC token contract (assuming it is called ABCToken)
import "ABCToken.sol";

contract Airdrop {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  // The contract owner's address
  address owner;

  // The address that will receive the airdropped ABC tokens
  address recipient;

  // The address of the BCD token contract
  BCDToken public bcdToken;

  // The address of the ABC token contract
  ABCToken public abcToken;

  // The amount of ABC tokens to airdrop
  uint256 public airdropAmount;

  constructor(address _owner, address _recipient, address _bcdToken, address _abcToken, uint256 _airdropAmount) public {
    owner = _owner;
    recipient = _recipient;
    bcdToken = BCDToken(_bcdToken);
    abcToken = ABCToken(_abcToken);
    airdropAmount = _airdropAmount;
  }

  // Listen for the Transfer event emitted by the BCD token contract
  event Transfer(
    address indexed _from,
    address indexed _to,
    uint256 _value
  );
  function() external payable {
    require(msg.sender == bcdToken, "Only the BCD token contract can call this function");
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, msg.data[0], msg.data[1]);
  }

  // Airdrop the ABC tokens when the Transfer event is emitted
  function onTransfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public {
    // Ensure that the recipient of the BCD tokens is the specified address
    require(_to == recipient, "The recipient of the BCD tokens is not the specified address");
    // Airdrop the ABC tokens to the recipient's address
    abcToken.transfer(_to, airdropAmount);
  }
}
```

First of all, try this in test-net firstly until you understand it totally.
It is important to note that this contract will only work if the BCD token contract is written to emit the Transfer event when a token transfer occurs. This event should include the from and to addresses of the transfer, as well as the amount of tokens transferred. You can check the documentation for the BCD token contract to see if it emits this event. If it does not, you will need to modify the contract to add this functionality.

and these are some more tips you should take care, that's why I ask to you to test firstly.

Yes, there are a few other things to consider when writing this contract:

`1. You should add some additional checks to ensure that the bcdToken and abcToken addresses are valid contract addresses and that they have been properly initialized.`

`2. You should also add some error handling to handle cases where the airdrop fails (e.g. if the recipient's address is invalid or if the ABC token contract does not have enough balance to perform the airdrop).`

`3. You may want to add some additional functionality to the contract, such as the ability to update the recipient address or the airdrop amount.`

`4. If you are planning to deploy this contract to the main Ethereum network, you should also consider the potential gas costs of performing the airdrop. Airdropping tokens to multiple recipients can be quite expensive in terms of gas, so you may want to add some additional logic to the contract to batch airdrops or limit the number of airdrops that can be performed in a given time period.`

Overall, it is important to carefully consider all of these factors when writing this contract to ensure that it is secure, efficient, and easy to use.

Web3 is not safe, take care once again.